# Why does this block not cycle through all my flash messages? - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So what I am trying to do is to apply a different class to the div containing the flash message depending on the type of flash message (i.e. error, notice, etc.).

I have this in my `application.html.erb`:

```
 <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <% if name = "error" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message error" %>
        <% elsif name = "notice" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message success" %>
        <% elsif name = "warning" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message warning" %>
        <% end %>
      <%- end -%>
```

But, it is always outputting a `div` with `id=flash_error`.

Why is that?

**Update 1**:

If I change the equality checks to be `==`, it seems to completely skip over that portion of the `if` statement.

```
 <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <% if name == "error" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message error" %>
        <% elsif name = "notice" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message success" %>
        <% elsif name == "warning" %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message warning" %>
        <% end %>
      <%- end -%>
```

If you notice, in the code above, I have `==` in for `error` and `warning` and I have `=` for `notice`. Well, in this case it actually outputs the `notice div` like I want it to. It seems that when I do a check for `="error"` it exits the conditional altogether, regardless of whether or not the check was right. But once I add `==` it doesn't even do the check it seems. Very bizarre!

Comment: I like to adopt coding conventions specifically to avoid this type of situation. Disciplining yourself to write `var.eql? "string" or `"string" == var` can save you debugging time.

Comment: But I do `var = "string"` here...so not sure what you mean.

Comment: Btw, in my case `name.eql "string"` doesn't work. It fails that condition and doesn't output the right `div`. So not sure what's going on.

Comment: `var == "string"` is the same thing as `"string" == var`. However, `var = "string"` is not the same thing as `"string" = var`. `"string" = var` will throw an exception. When you code checks for equality, disciplining yourself to write `"string" == var` will save you debugging time - when you accidentally type `"string" = var`, you will uncover the problem faster.

Comment: Oh ok...I get you. You are right. That was sloppy on my end.

Comment: In your case, you want `name.eql? :some_symbol`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be because you are not checking for equality?

Not a check for equality

```
<% if name = "error" %>
```

A check for equality

```
<% if name == "error" %>
```

It could also be that you are checking for a string. The flash hash is indexed by symbols.

Try

```
<% if name == :error %>
```

Comment: Now it's not display the flash message at all.

Comment: Perfect...that last bit worked. Seems it doesn't like the check for a `string`, but would rather `:symbol`.

Comment: Btw, where can I get info on the various symbols I can use in the flash hash? As in, can I use `flash[:warning]`? If so, what else can be used? Anything?